# Find all functions where $f^2(x)f'(x)\geq x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Find all $f:(0, +\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ derivative functions where $$f^2(x)f'(x)\geq x^2$$ and $$|f(x)|\leq x(1+e^{-x})$$ for all positive $x$.

Multiplying by $3$ the first inequality we obtain that $f^3(x)-x^3$ is monotone increasing, so there exists $$\lim_{x\to0} f^3(x)-x^3$$ which from the second inequality we deduce that it equals $0$. That means that $f(x)\geq x$ and that's where my work stopped. It is clear that $f(x)=x$ is such a function but I can't find another one or prove that this is the only one. Can you please help me?

Comment: You keep saying "derivative function". I think you mean "differentiable function"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first inequality means $f(x)^3 = x^3 + g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is differentiable and nondecreasing. As you note, $f(0) = 0$, so $g(x) \ge 0$.  Now the second inequality gives you
$$ g(x) = f(x)^3 - x^3 \le x^3 (3 e^{-x} + 3 e^{-2x} + e^{-3x})$$
But the right side goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$, so $g(x) = 0$.